# SonarQube Ant task, failed to download the file

Tags: java, ant, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I am running a simple Ant script for SonarQube and have the following error:

> FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\c5187668\sap\simpleAnt.sonar\batch\sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar|99845a2f47eaef85b29978725f82c50c"

- SonarQube Server Version 5.1.2
- Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
- Sonar Ant Task version: 2.0
- Java 1.6 - so, we cannot use modern version of Sonar Ant.

Can it be fixed somehow? Any ideas?

The Ant script:

```
<project name="sonar build" default="Sonar" basedir="." xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant">

<taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
    <classpath path="sonar-ant-task.jar"/>
</taskdef>
<!-- Out-of-the-box those parameters are optional -->
<property name="sonar.jdbc.url" value="dbc:mysql://?????:3306/sonardb?useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf8" />
<property name="sonar.jdbc.driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="sonar.jdbc.username" value="?????" />
<property name="sonar.jdbc.password" value="?????" />
<!-- Additional Sonar configuration (PMD need 1.5 when using annotations)-->
<property name="sonar.java.source" value="1.6"/>
<property name="sonar.java.target" value="1.6"/>    
<property name="sonar.projectName" value="SonarBuild"/>
<property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="2.0" />
<!-- SERVER ON A REMOTE HOST -->
<property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://??????" />
<target name="Sonar">
    <sonar:sonar />
</target>
```

I got the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED C:\Users\c5187668\sap\simpleAnt\build.xml:17:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download libraries from
server
        at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.downloadBatchFiles(Bootstrapper.java:166)
        at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.createClassLoader(Bootstrapper.java:89)
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.createClassLoader(Runner.java:229)
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:151)
        at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.launchAnalysis(SonarTask.java:93)
        at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.execute(SonarTask.java:75)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:853)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112) Caused
by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download the file:
http://???????/batch/sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar|99845a2f47eaef85b29
978725f82c50c

        at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.remoteContentToFile(Bootstrapper.java:115)
        at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.downloadBatchFiles(Bootstrapper.java:161)
        ... 22 more Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\c5187668\sap\simpleAnt\.sonar\batch\sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar|99845a2f47eaef85b29978725f82c50c
(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
        at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.remoteContentToFile(Bootstrapper.java:109)
        ... 23 more

Total time: 0 seconds
```

P.S. by question marks ????? I hide real server name and credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Ant Task version (2.0) is not compatible with your SonarQube version. This [compatibility matrix](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Analyzing+Source+Code#AnalyzingSourceCode-CompatibilityMatrix) shows that v2.2 is a minimum requirement since SonarQube 3.7 (2.4 being the best choice for SonarQube 4.5+).

You should upgrade your [SonarQube Scanner for Ant](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Ant) and also use a [supported version of Java](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements).

Comment: Ok, thank you. But we are using java 1.6 which is not compatible with Sonar Ant Task 2.2 and further.

Comment: Understood, but there's no other solution than upgrading Java at this point. Not to mention that Java 6 is quite ancient and not supported anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You told *Ant* that your SonarQube server is running at `http://??????` , the script therefore fails (quite understandably) to download the resources it needs from the server.

Fix this:

`<property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://??????" />`

The value should be the URL you use to browse your SonarQube server's homepage.

P.S.: you'll also have to fix `sonar.jdbc.username` and `sonar.jdbc.password`

Comment: By question marks I just hide real server name and real credentials.